# Grouping data with python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm new to python and I'm trying to bundle data from two dataframes but I don't get the expected result. The data are as follows:

```
data = {'Code':['xxy','zzy','rrf','ado'], 
        'Service':["23a","22c","21d","24o"],
        'Service2':["44e", "32c","85a","26f"],
        'Service3':["42e", "32z","8m","2c"],
       }

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df
```

```
days = {'Services':['23a','23a','44e','zzy', "8m", "8m", "8m", "26f", "8m", "2c", "24o", "26f" ], 
        'Type days':["Monday","Tuesday","Tuesday","Wednesday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Monday", "Wednesday", "Monday", "Tuesday"]
       }
df2 = pd.DataFrame(days)
df2
```

I would like to get something like this,
[expected result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NmgaE.png)

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Thornos,

I see that the data you have provided are not matching to the output you are expecting. The 2 dataframe does not have common data which can result in the output you provided . For example if you do join the 2 dataframe it will result as below

```
df4=df.merge(df2,on='Service',how='outer')
```

[image]

further when you remove the rows with NAN values you will get

```
df4.dropna( inplace=True)
```

[image]

so you may need to work on your input data to get expected result.

Comment: You're right, but you gave me a good idea.  Thank you! Is there a way to merge several columns at once or would I have to do it one by one?

Comment: you can do multiple column join at once, if the column names are common then syntax will be df.merge(df2,on=['Service','Codes'],how='outer') . however if the column names of two data frame are different then df.merge(df2,left_on=['Service','Codes'],right_on=['Service1','Codes1'] ,how='outer'). this is just a example.